# Sqlite always returns only 1 row

Tags: ios, sqlite

The count returns 3 ,as i have 3 rows in the column. But when i try to publish the name , it only returns 1 row.

please take a look at my code.

```
  sqlite3_stmt *statement;
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_chatDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"SELECT MESSAGE from CHATCOMPLETE"];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_chatDB,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
         if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                              (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                           NSLog(@"Name is %@",name);
            }

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Not found");
         //   return nil;
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but instead of `sqlite3_reset`, you want to use `sqlite3_finalize`. `sqlite3_reset` is for resetting a prepared statement so you can bind new variables to `?` placeholders in the SQL and execute it again (which is not the case here), whereas `sqlite3_finalize` will free the memory consumed by preparing the statement. I'd also suggest logging `sqlite3_errmsg(_chatDB)` if the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `if/else` to a `while` to step through all the rows:

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                       NSLog(@"Name is %@",name);
}
```

Then you can process all of the results.

And you should change `sqlite3_reset` to `sqlite3_finalize`. And don't forget to close the database too.

Comment: Thank you so much ,that was the problem.

Comment: @rob Thank you Rob , i did it but it asked me to wait for 7 minutes, But thank you again.